# Connecting a SIP app to RingCentral server

Tags: ios, sip, voip, ringcentral

I'm attempting to connect a SIP iOS app to a digital SIP line hosted by RingCentral. The settings for the line, as given by RingCentral, are:

```
SIP Domain: sip.ringcentral.com:5060
Outbound proxy: sip11.ringcentral.com:5090
Username: 12148656048
Password: -password-
Authorization ID: -same as password-
```

So, I've set up the SIP app like this:

```
-Identity Settings-

Display name: Line1
Public id: sip:12148656048@sip.ringcentral.com
Private id: 12148656048
Password: -password-
Realm: sip.ringcentral.com

-Network settings-

Proxy Host: sip11.ringcentral.com
Proxy Port: 5090
Transport: UDP
Enable SigComp: OFF

-NAT Traversal settings-

Enable STUN: OFF
Discover: OFF
Server: numb.viagenie.ca
Port: 3478
```

My app fails to connect to the server. Can anybody spot the error there? FYI the app i'm using is [iDoubs](https://github.com/DoubangoTelecom/idoubs), and I've been able to connect this to multiple SIP servers such as `sip2sip.info` and `voipraider.com`. Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: Here is a post on their board which talks about setting up a similar app on Android - [LINK](http://forum.ringcentral.com/viewtopic.php?p=6568&sid=8f34998c8092b25f8e3944c11a92e131). I've posted this question on their board as well but have yet to get a reply.

Comment: You should ask Ring Central. They are VERY picky about devices, even if you get one on their recommended list it might not work.. Why not use their app?

Comment: I'm writing my own app based on the open source iDoubs project, and I want to have an actual phone number assigned to it, which will call the app. I'll call ringcentral soon to see if they can help, even though I haven't heard anything good about their support.

Comment: See more information on RingCentral and BYOD SIP here: https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/4966 . The RingCentral success team can assist with this here: https://success.ringcentral.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

[Tyler from RingCentral](https://github.com/tylerlong) Has a demo using SIP.js connecting to RingCentral SIP server, here: https://github.com/tylerlong/ringcentral-webrtc/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article to configure RingCentral for Zoiper: https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/setup-zoiper-as-a-ringcentral-device-ad484a81d317

If iDoubs is a similar product as Zoiper you should be able to setup it as well.